# Removing Signature from xml

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xml-signature

I would like to discard signature element from my xml files. So I use xslt for filtering some elements and tags from my xml files. I use xslt with python. Xslt looks like the following:

```
xslt_root = etree.XML('''\
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

                <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
                  <xsl:copy>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                  </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:template>


                <xsl:template match="TimeStamp"/>
                <xsl:template match="@timeStamp"/>
                <xsl:template match="TimeStamps"/>
                <xsl:template match="Signature"/>

                </xsl:stylesheet>
                ''')
```

The problem is that when I save the result(updated) xml files, all elements and tags which I have defined in the xslt rule will be discarded except "Signature" element which remains. Is there a possible way to discard this signature from xml file?

Comment: Please post your source XML - together with the XML output you get versus what you expected. Otherwise we will not be able to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Signature` element has a namespace, for example:

```
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">...</Signature>
```

Then you'll need to adapt your XSLT to match it with the namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> <!-- CHANGE #1 -->

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TimeStamp"/>
  <xsl:template match="@timeStamp"/>
  <xsl:template match="TimeStamps"/>
  <xsl:template match="s:Signature"/>  <!-- CHANGE #2 -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice idea but it didn't work..I added the namespace as u mentioned.